# Difference between following phrases

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

Difference in meaning:

> 1. "I **wouldn't** make it "
> 2. "I **didn't** make it"

where using the first phrase to express something that wasn't done instead of the second phrase confuses me.

Comment: It really helps to use correct spelling for questions, especially capital letters and apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A month ago, I knew **I wouldn't make it** to class yesterday, because I
>   had a doctor's appointment scheduled.
>
> I **did not make it** to class yesterday because I had to see the doctor.

The first, with **wouldn't**, refers to the future relative to a point in time in the past.

The second, with **did not make it**, is simple past, referring to what happened  (or did not happen) in the past.